# Responsive HTML Table with reverse collapsible rows

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive-design

I have a table looking like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p856W.jpg

```html
<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Unbefristete Lizenzen</td>
                <td>–</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Abo-Lizenzen</td>
                <td>Als monatliche und jährliche Subscription</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lizenzierung</td>
                <td>Pro User</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

It's made scrollable on mobile with a div container around it with overflow-x... it looks really ugly. I'd like the rows to collapse like it would do in a normal responsive layout with columns.

So it would look like this on mobile:

Headline
Data
Headline
Data

Any ideas how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot stack `<td>` in one `<tr>` so if you have a headline with data, I think you need a `<br>` like this `<td>headline<br>Data</td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add breakpoint and change `<td>` style but it's a little bit tricky. This can cause other problems depending on how you use `<table>` but it should be fine if you only use table naively.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 567px) {
   td { 
        width:100%;
        display:block;
     }
    }
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks a lot. So easy... already tried that but forgot the "display: block" .... :D ... I only use the table tag for native tables so that should be fine.

Comment: @flip no problem. Since you modify `<td>` for all tables. You might be aware if you use table somewhere else in the future.

Comment: I'll keep an eye on that. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should realize that with a CSS grid. That does the trick cleanly